# Determine number of squares in progressively decreasing size that can be carved out of a rectangle

Tags: geometry, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

How many squares in progressively decreasing size can be created from a rectangle of dimension $a\;X\;b$

For example, consider a rectangle of dimension $3\;X\;8$
[image]

As you can see, the biggest square that you can carve out of it is of dimension $3\;X\;3$ and they are ABFE and EFGH

The next biggest square is of dimension $2\;X\;2$ which is GJIC

Followed by two other squares of dimension $2\;X\;2$ which are JHLK and KLDI

So the answer is 5.

Is there any mathematical approach of solving it for a rectangle of arbitrary dimension?

Comment: I have full faith that you have the stamina to type out the word "number" rather than just typing "no," so please use "number instead!

Comment: @rschwieb: Its more of a habit rather than a stamina. Sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the algorithm you seem to be doing, cutting the largest possible square off a rectangle, it is a simple recursive algorithm.  If you start with an $n \times m$ rectangle with $n \ge m$, you will cut off $\lfloor \frac nm \rfloor m \times m$ squares and be left with a $(n-\lfloor \frac nm \rfloor m) \times m$ rectangle.  Then you remove as many $(n-\lfloor \frac nm \rfloor m)$ squares as you can and continue.  The smallest square will be the greatest common divisor of $n$ and $m$

Answer (score 0):

Mathematically, start with the [square pyramidal number](http://oeis.org/A000330) under the rectangle's area, and compare with the list of known [tightly packed rectangles](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/TightlyPackedSquares/), which usually have low [excess values](http://oeis.org/A081287).  You could see if a given rectangle is at [squaring.net](http://squaring.net/) for known perfect packings.

It's quickly a hard problem.  For example, can a $189\times189$ or $190\times188$ rectangle be cut into 47 decreasing squares?  This problem is too combinatorially hard to solve at the moment.